# How to test if a regular expression engine is greedy by default?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm sleepy, and not thinking clearly, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match `aa*` against `aa` and see if it matches one or two `a`s?

Comment: can you use an example in javascript to test it? please, I did not understand

Comment: `if ( "aa".match(/aa*/)[0] == "a" ) alert("ungreedy"); else alert("greedy");`

Comment: But there's really no point, since the greediness of JavaScript regexps is [well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark). `a*`, `a+`, `a?` and `a{1,3}` are greedy, `a*?`, `a+?`, `a??` and `a{1,3}?` are ungreedy.